# OpenAPI generator Maven Plugin gives error "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, openapi-generator

While generating a client from an api.json file I encounter a couple of error messages "cannot find symbol". I googled for the package and class name but didn't find anything. Here is the pom I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
<artifactId>myClient</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
        <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.json</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                        <configOptions>
                            <asyncNative>true</asyncNative>
                            <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                            <sourceFolder>src/gen/java</sourceFolder>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Following is the console output I get:

```
target/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java/org/openapitools/client/api/MessagesV3Api.java[239,43] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class CreateMessageEnvelopeDTO
location: class org.openapitools.client.api.MessagesV3Api
```

Here is the json api spec file for reproduction:

````
    {
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "OpenAPI definition",
    "version": "v0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {"url":"https://int.zbp.bund.de","description":"ZBP-INT"}
  ],
  "security": [
    {
      "bearerAuth": []
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "Messages V3",
      "description": "Get, create or manipulate messages."
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/v3/mailbox/messages": {
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "Messages V3"
        ],
        "summary": "Insert a message into a Mailbox",
        "description": "## This endpoint inserts a message into the specified mailbox.\n**Returns** an object with ids for the newly created message\n",
        "operationId": "putMessageV3",
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "Multipartform of a signed CreateMessageDTO and attachments.\n\nJson part should always be first and must contain content length of the attachment in the Attachments list.\n\n### curl example:\n\n```-F 'json={....}'```\n```-F 'files=@sample.txt;type=text/plain'```\n\n",
          "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateMessageMultiPartDoc"
              },
              "encoding": {
                "files": {
                  "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
                  "headers": {
                    "Content-Length": {
                      "description": "This contains the length of the file in bytes.",
                      "required": true,
                      "style": "simple",
                      "schema": {
                        "type": "integer"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "The id of the created message is returned.",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateMessageResponseDTO"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "`ZBP_400_006: field missing for filename in Attachment in json content.`\n\n\n`ZBP_400_001: Type mismatch for parameter {parameter}`\n\n`ZBP_400_001: parameter {parameter} not valid`\n\n`ZBP_400_001: {constraintViolation}`",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponseDTO"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "`ZBP_401_001: malformed authorization token`",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "errorCode": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "the machine readable error code for the current error"
                    },
                    "description": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "a human readable description of the error"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "`ZBP_403_002: Given signature does not match with message content. Please re-sign and try again.`\n",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponseDTO"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "`ZBP_404_003: Can't find this mailbox.`",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "errorCode": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "the machine readable error code for the current error"
                    },
                    "description": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "a human readable description of the error"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "409": {
            "description": "`ZBP_409_001: no trust level`\n\n`ZBP_409_002: no subject in token`\n\n`ZBP_409_003: wrong trust level`",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "errorCode": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "the machine readable error code for the current error"
                    },
                    "description": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "a human readable description of the error"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "413": {
            "description": "`ZBP_413_001: Number of allowed attachments exceeded.`\n\n`ZBP_413_002: Sum of attachments size exceeded limit.`\n",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponseDTO"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "429": {
            "description": "`ZBP_429_001: Rate limit was exceeded.`",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "errorCode": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "the machine readable error code for the current error"
                    },
                    "description": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "a human readable description of the error"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "`ZBP_500_006: error processing request`\n\n\n`ZBP_500_011: internal servlet error occurred`\n\n`ZBP_500_012: Please check logs for more information`",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponseDTO"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "503": {
            "description": "`ZBP_503_001: error uploading to file storage`\n",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ErrorResponseDTO"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "CreateMessageEnvelopeDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "content": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "{\n    \"mailboxUuid\": \"12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012\",\n    \"stork_qaa_level\": 0,\n    \"sender\": \"string\",\n    \"title\": \"string\",\n    \"content\": \"string\",\n    \"service\": \"string\",\n    \"senderUrl\": \"string\",\n    \"reference\": \"string\",\n    \"retrievalConfirmationAddress\": \"string\",\n    \"replyAddress\": \"string\",\n    \"attachments\": [\n      {\n        \"filename\": \"string\",\n        \"sha512sum\": \"string\"\n        \"content-length\": \"long\"\n      }\n    ]\n  }"
          },
          "sha512sum": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the signature of the above content"
          }
        }
      },
      "CreateMessageMultiPartDoc": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "json": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateMessageEnvelopeDTO"
          },
          "files": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "files to upload. Needs Content-Length header.\n\n### curl example:\n\n```-F 'files=@sample.txt;type=text/plain;headers=\"Content-Length: 200000\"```",
              "format": "binary"
            }
          }
        },
        "description": "File parts need Content-Length header.\n\n### curl example:\n\n```-F 'files=@sample.txt;type=text/plain;headers=\\\"Content-Length: 200000\\\"```\n\n(swagger-ui is broken and ignores encoding.)\n"
      },
      "ErrorResponseDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "errorCode": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the machine readable error code for the current error"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "a human readable description of the error"
          }
        }
      },
      "CreateMessageResponseDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "mailboxHandle": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the uuid of the mailbox",
            "format": "uuid"
          },
          "messageId": {
            "type": "integer",
            "description": "the long id for the message for compatibility reasons",
            "format": "int64"
          },
          "messageUuid": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the uuid of the message",
            "format": "uuid"
          }
        }
      },
      "CreateMessageDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "mailboxUuid": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "This is the mailbox for the message",
            "format": "uuid"
          },
          "stork_qaa_level": {
            "type": "integer",
            "description": "the stork qaa level of the message",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "sender": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the sender of the message"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the title of the message"
          },
          "content": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the content of the message"
          },
          "service": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the service of the message"
          },
          "senderUrl": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the senderUrl of the message"
          },
          "reference": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the case reference of the message"
          },
          "retrievalConfirmationAddress": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the retrieval confirmation address of the message"
          },
          "replyAddress": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the reply address of the message"
          },
          "attachments": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/CreateAttachmentDTO"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "CreateAttachmentDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "filename": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "the filename of the attachment"
          },
          "sha512sum": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "This is the sha512 checksum of the file. It will be verified on upload."
          },
          "contentLength": {
            "type": "integer",
            "description": "Content length of the attachment",
            "format": "int64"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes": {
      "bearerAuth": {
        "type": "http",
        "description": "Create your token with your certificate.",
        "scheme": "bearer",
        "bearerFormat": "JWT"
      }
    }
  }
}
````

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with OpenAPI Generator (for reference, see e.g. [1](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/12036), [2](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/14461), [3](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/14681), [4](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10254)).

Your output from maven/OpenAPI-Generator contains this line:

```
[INFO] Model CreateMessageEnvelopeDTO not generated since it's marked as unused (due to form parameters) and `skipFormModel` (global property) set to true (default)
```

To set the mentioned `skipFormModel` property and solve the compilation error, add this to your pom's `<configuration>` section:

```xml
<globalProperties>
    <skipFormModel>false</skipFormModel>
</globalProperties>
```

Comment: take care:  <globalProperties> must be directly inside <configuration>, 
not inside <configOptions>